# Steinhaus's Easter Egg Problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview, translation, irrational-numbers

The following is the text of Steinhaus's so-called Easter egg problem. According to [this article](http://kielich.amu.edu.pl/Stefan_Banach/e-duda.html) of Roman Duda, this was recorded in the New Scottish Book around Easter 1955 and "Steinhaus offered an Easter egg (decorated by him personally) as a prize."

This question has two parts:

1. Provide an English translation of the Polish text
2. Report on the status of the problem

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is Włodzimierz Holsztyński's translation (that he deleted) with my finish:

A circle $K$ has circumference $1$. $O$ belongs to $K$, and it is a beginning of the time axis which is wounded around $K$. On this axis the time intervals of consecutive lengths $1,\frac 12,\frac 13,\dots,\frac 1n,\ldots$ are positioned in a way that $n$-th interval $I_n$ is given by $\ I_n = \langle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac 1k,\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k\rangle$. The time-points $t_n=n\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is irrational (e.g. $\alpha=\frac{\sqrt 5-1}2$), are considered to be signals if and only if $t_n\in I_n$ on $K$.

CLAIM to be PROVED [Włodzimierz Holsztyński stopped here]: Show that the signals constitute a Poisson process of rate parameter $1$, i.e. the relative measure of those $x$'s for which the interval $\langle x, x+\ell\rangle$ contains exactly $k$ signals is $\frac{\ell^k}{k!}e^{-\ell}$.

Comment: (Steinhaus description: *effectively*, is missing). GH from MO, your action was ugly. For everybody else: there is a difference between style and **rigid** rules. GH is insensitive to this disctiction.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński: I always act in good beliefs, and I am truly sorry if I hurt your feelings. Feel free to edit my post, correct and complete the translation etc. This site is not about persons but about mathematics. (For everybody else: I simply deleted some spaces from Włodzimierz Holsztyński's original formulae, I had no idea this action would be considered **ugly** by him.)

Comment: Friends, remember the Easter spirit.

Comment: Thank you, both. I'm a bit unclear on how exactly to make sense of the question as translated. Can anyone offer a clear interpretation of this?

Comment: @MarkLewko: The way I interpret it is as follows. If $X\to\infty$, then the measure of $x\in[0,X]$ such $\#\{n\in[x,x+\ell]:\ t_n\in I_n\}=k$ equals $\frac{\ell^k}{k!}e^{-\ell}X+o(X)$.

Comment: Gentlemen: please read http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2208/editing-etiquette @WłodzimierzHolsztyński

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Thanks for this meta entry. I am really sorry what happened to Włodzimierz Holsztyński's post. I did not realize that having extra spaces at both ends of each of his formulae was style for him, I really thought of it as going against TeX's own philosophy (which includes "leave the spacing to me") that he might not be aware of. At any rate, I will not commit the same mistake again, and let people stick to their own style even if I find it **ugly** typesetting.

Comment: @GHfromMO No worries; I don't think you need to apologize for the action, i.e., I think you had meant to be helpful. And also this particular thread is not really the focal point for the meta post; it's something that comes up now and then, and I just wanted something to point people to in the future.